# Multiple-entry visas on arrival in Kathmandu

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, visas-on-arrival, multiple-entry, nepal

Is it possible for a British passport holder to get a 15-day multiple-entry visa on arrival at Kathmandu airport?  The information online seems inconsistent about whether it's only single-entry visas that can be obtained on arrival.  I know I can get one in advance from the Nepalese embassy, but that's not very convenient as there are limited times when I can be without my passport and I have a few other visas to sort out before departing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Nepalese visa regulations state that multiple-entry tourist visas for up to 90-days can be obtained both on arrival](http://www.nepalimmigration.gov.np/?page_id=112), as well as by [applying prior to travelling](http://online.nepalimmigration.gov.np/tourist-visa). The application to the Director General is however required to renew the visa within the same visa year. Quoting from the linked website:

[image: Nepal tourist visa]

The visa fees are summarised in [Appendix 9 of the regulations](http://www.nepalimmigration.gov.np/?page_id=114) and are of:

[image: Nepal visa fees]

Note however that as of June 2014 [Visa on arrival facilities in Nepal are not available to  Nigeria, Ghana, Zimbabwe, Cameroon, Swaziland, Somalia, Ethiopia, Liberia, Iraq, Palestine and Afaganisthan nationals.](http://www.nepalimmigration.gov.np/?recent_update_news=on-arrival-visa-facility-for-the-diplomats-officials-and-relatives-of-nigeria-ghana-zimbabwe-cameroon-swaziland-somalia-liberia-iraq-palestine-and-afaganisthan)

Comment: The table of fees only lists multiple-entry fees, so I guess there isn't any other sort.  If so, that answers the question.  Thanks.